# Convert string "12:00:34" time to angular js time 12:00:34

Tags: angularjs

image show the model in which time will be shown but right now it is not properly binding

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string to date object like as

```
var myDateStr = "12:00:34";
var dateArray = myDateStr.split(":");
$scope.myDate = new Date(1970, 0, 1, dateArray[0], dateArray[1], dateArray[2]);
```

And Use `myDate` in html

Comment: thank you sooooo much bro i was doing same just missed to put default date   you save hell a lot of time <3